# Unit testing void methods for repository

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mocking, tdd, repository

I want to test my void repository. My service class like this.

```
public class AccountService
{
    private readonly IAccountRepository accountRepository;

    public AccountService(IAccountRepository accountRepository)
    {
        this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
    }

    public User GetById(string userId)
    {
        User user = accountRepository.GetById(userId);

        if (user == null)
            throw new UserNotFoundException();

        return user;
    }

    public void Add(User user)
    {
        accountRepository.Add(user);
    }
}
```

In my test class I created a fake repository that using FakeItEasy tool.

```
[TestFixture]
public class AccountServiceTests
{
    private IAccountRepository repository;
    private AccountService service;

    private  string ValidUserId = "aaa";
    private  string InvalidUserId = "xxx";

    private List<User> getUsers()
    {
        return new List<User> {new User {UserId = ValidUserId}};
    }

    private readonly User newUser= new User();

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        repository = A.Fake<IAccountRepository>();
        service = new AccountService(repository);

        A.CallTo(() => repository.GetById(ValidUserId))
            .Returns(new User{UserId = ValidUserId});

        A.CallTo(() => repository.GetById(InvalidUserId))
            .Returns(null);

        A.CallTo(() => repository.Add(A<User>.Ignored))
            .???
    }

    [Test]
    public void GetUser_ValidUserId_ReturnsUser()
    {
        User user = service.GetById(ValidUserId);

        Assert.IsNotNull(user);
        Assert.AreEqual(ValidUserId, user.UserId);
    }

    [Test, ExpectedException(typeof(UserNotFoundException))]
    public void GetUser_InValidUserId_ThrowsUserNotFoundException()
    {
       service.GetById(InvalidUserId);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Add_User_AddsUser()
    {
        service.Add(newUser);
    }
}
```

I can test the GetUser method successfull. But I can not test the Add method in my service class. Because it is not returning anything. Or I service class has no List that included users to chack status. What do you recommend about testing this void method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the FakeItEasy [documentation](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy), you can use the `.MustHaveHappened()` method i.e.

```
[Test]
public void Add_User_AddsUser()
{
    service.Add(newUser);
    A.CallTo(() => repository.Add(A<User>.Ignored)).MustHaveHappened();         
}
```

Comment: what means MustHaveHappened, wtiting only Assertion in documentation. Should I use it after service.Add(newUser);

Comment: "Must have happened" checks that repository.Add() has been called when you you call service.Add().  If repository.Add() hasn't been called, the test will fail.  If it has, the test will pass.

By checking that repository.Add() gets called, you are asserting that calling service.Add() makes the repository call.  It's then up to the repository to actually add the user.